# how many data types does boost variant support?

Tags: c++, boost-variant

Consider the following:

```
// what is N?
typedef boost::variant<T1, ..., TN> variant_t;
```

How many template parameters are acceptable here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the documentation:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES.html

```
// In header: <boost/variant/variant_fwd.hpp>

BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES
```