# Nesting boost variant types to increase the type limit?

Tags: c++, boost-variant

Consider:

```
typedef boost::variant<T0, ..., TN> variant_T_t;
typedef boost::variant<U0, ..., UN> variant_U_t;
...
typedef boost::variant<variant_T_t, variant_U_t, ...> variant_t;
```

This extends the [limit on the number of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027640/how-many-data-types-does-boost-variant-support) that can be held by my type to `pow(BOOST_VARIANT_LIMIT_TYPES, L)`, where `L` is the number of levels nested.

Is this (to an extent) an acceptable solution, or is it just a bad hack?  Is there a better solution out there?  Perhaps the old-fashioned `union` is more appropriate?

Comment: The proper solution is just to redefine the macro, Goddammit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an ugly hack. It will make your visitors or your get calls extremely ugly and unreadable.

Try just increasing the limit instead - Boost.Variant defines it to be the same as `BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_LIST_SIZE`, which you can override if you disable the pre-generated headers (which is a hit in compile time, though).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/limit-list-size.html

Why do you need this crazy amount of different types anyway? This sounds like a potential design issue.

Comment: There won't be an extreme amount, but *potentially* more than our `variant` implementation's limit defined at 20.

Answer (score 4):

As of boost 1.57, boost variant can be created via `boost::make_variant_over`, which takes a type Sequence as a type parameter. There is no type limitation on that type until that models boost::mpl's *Sequence* Concept.

The vanilla boost::mpl::vector typelist can be used up to 50 types. 
Though if you have a C++11 compliant compiler, then it is not so  hard to create your own variadic typelist and a glue code for that, which makes that to be an MPL *Sequence*. And from this point, the number of types is limited by the compiler's allowed maximum template instantiation depth, which is usually 256.

In this [GIST](https://gist.github.com/martong/d526cc36c08dce8367f2), I am taking Dave Abraham's typelist and adding the glue code, so it models mpl's sequence concept. Note, that I'have not done exhausting testing on several compilers, also I just tested it with boost 1.56.